# Easily move an off-topic question to another board, without down votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, down-votes

Why not provide a way for the original question asker, or the admins of a board to move the question to a more appropriate location without incurring down-vote penalties to the asker?

Comment: A board? What's that?

Comment: Moderators already have the means to migrate questions.

Comment: OK, thanks, how about the original user, when I realize I get down voted because I asked my question in the wrong place, I would like to move it myself, without waiting for a moderator, or keep incurring down-votes from unforgiving users.

Comment: @Victor how about asking it in the right place in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

We already have that, users with over 3,000 reputation can vote to migrate a question to a more suitable site,  choosing from a small list of related sites and diamond moderators can vote to migrate to any site on the Stack Exchange network.

When a down voted question is migrated, the down votes are cleared on the target site. However if the question is up voted, the up votes follow it to the target site.

As the original asker, you always have the option of deleting your question and then asking it on another site, deleting the question will also refund any reputation you lost from downvotes. However don't just assume that your question is more suitable to another site because someone happened to mention it in a comment, questions that *actually* fit another site do get migrated. We might miss one or two, but in general when a question is closed instead of moved, you can assume that it doesn't really fit another site.

Comment: Can the origin asker do this themselves? This would potentially reduce the work required to be done by moderators in some cases.

Comment: @VictorS As the original poster, if you have 3K rep, you can vote to migrate, but as a regular user you still need four more votes. You can always flag for moderation attention and ask for your question to be migrated.

Comment: Why such a high threshold for the user who asked the question himself? I don't think any threshold should exist.

Comment: @VictorS Well, if the user who asked the question knew that there was a more appropriate site for it, why did he ask it on the wrong site in the first place? The threshold is the same for everyone, the user who asked the question may vote to migrate if they want, but in general that's an extremely rare occasion, users who know that their question would be more suitable at another site, well, ask it there.